# Calling andthen on 2 functions don't require them to have the same return value?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to understand how the below code works.  How is it that the f1 function can chain the calls using `andThen` when the return types don't align exactly?

It seems the Future[Int] value of inner2 is lost when I call it last in the function `f1`.

So from what I understand the flow works like this:

1. `f1` is called passing user as an argument.
2. `inner1` is called, passing user and it returns the Future of either boolean or user.
3. the `andThen` is called, passing user as an argument, but somehow also passing the return value of the call to `inner1`?  Is this curried??
4. Doesn't `inner2` respond with a different return type, how is the Future[Int] just lost?

The code:

```
def f1(user: User): Future[Either[Boolean, User]] = 
  inner1(user) andThen inner2(user)
    
def inner1(user: User): Future[Either[Boolean, User]] = ???
def inner2(user: User): PartialFunction[Try[Either[Boolean, User]], Future[Int]] = ???
```

Comment: Check the [**Scaldoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#andThen[U](pf:PartialFunction[scala.util.Try[T],U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[T]), you are NOT calling `andThen` on a **function** but on a **Future** which is used to register side effectual callbacks, not chaining `Futures` together. It seems you would want to use `transforWith` but you would need to ensure your function is total not partial.

Comment: @jwvh I meant Try[Either[..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inner1()` returns a `Future`.

As @LuisMiguel has pointed out, you're calling `andThen()` on that `Future`

`andThen()`, on a `Future`, takes a `PartialFunction[Try[T],U]` where `T` is the `Future`'s return type, in this case `Either[Boolean,User]`.

The `PartialFunction`, i.e. `inner2()`, is applied as a side-effecting callback on the `Future`, so its return value, the `Future[Int]` in this case, is discarded.